# InjectionManagerFactory not found in OSGi http service with Declarative service

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

[tag:We are migrating our jetty, jersey library to non vulnerable version for our OSGi project which is based on Declarative service (Apache SCR) and for all the rest API/resource we are getting 404

Here is the OSGi and jar version

`org.osgi.core` version 6.0.0
`org.apache.felix.http.jetty` version 4.2.22
`org.osgi.compendium` version 5.0.0
`org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-util` version 2.6.1
`org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-api` version 2.6.1
`org.glassfish.hk2.hk2-locator` version 2.6.1
`org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject` version 2.6.1
`org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator` version 1.0.3
`org.apache.felix.scr` version 2.1.26
`org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server` version 2.41
`org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-client` version 2.41
`org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common` version 2.41
`org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core` version 2.41
`org.glassfish.jersey.media.jersey-media-json-jackson` version 2.41
`org.glassfish.jersey.ext.jersey-entity-filtering` version 2.41

also using
`com.google.inject.guice` version 4.0 for additional Binding

After upgrading version we were able to compile the code with JDK 11.
Deploying the generated bundles into Apache Felix but at deployment we are getting InjectionManagerFactory not found error, so we have added `org.glassfish.jersey.inject.jersey-hk2` version 2.41 in pom but no use also tried to add in bnd.bnd file also in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file but still getting same issue.
Before adding `jersey-hk2` in pom my unit test case were also failing with same error but now my test cases are running successfully after adding `jersey-hk2` jar but at runtime still at,

`org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.lookupService(Class clazz)` of `jersey-common`

getting InjectionMangerFactory not found. Please guide us to resolve the issue

How OSGI will pick up that `jersey-hk2` jar at runtime.]